# Efficient way of checking similar possible inputs?

Tags: python, if-statement

What is the most efficient way to check an input that can be written in different ways without a repeated "or" function? (i. e. a shorter version to write:

if answer == "Yes" or answer == "yes" or answer == YES

Thanks!

Comment: For that specific case: `if answer.ToUpper() == "YES"` or if the language supports case-agnostic string comparisons, you could use those instead. Taken from C#: `answer.Equals("yes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Comment: @EtienneMaheu No ! What about answer is null ?! Better is "YES".equals(answer.toUpper()) in Java or explicitly check nulllness of answer in other languages

Comment: @kulatamicuda Most of the time, null is not a concern. If it would be then I would go for `answer?.Equals(...)` instead (in C# again) or some equivalent. Yoda conditions are horrible to read and I would avoid them at all cost. I would even prefer to write extension methods to deal with this case (in C# again): `answer.SelectOrDefault(a => a.Equals(...))`. Still, good point. Null values are a pain.

Comment: @EtienneMaheu never underestimate the billion dollar mistake :) Yes, the better solution for beginner would be to explicitelly check nullness via ? in C# or use Optionals in Java than Yoda expressions.

Comment: I misunderstood your question at first...Etienne Maheu has the right idea.  Just cast toUpper or toLower and check for null.

Comment: @kulatamicuda I guess my point is more that having a null value there would mean that something went terribly wrong in the way over there and you should probably stop what you are doing anyway (throw an exception) and fix that issue first. I have seen a "billion dollar mistake" because somebody did null-checked everything which hid a deeper issue in the code for years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
valid = ["Yes", "yes", "y", "ok"]

if answer in valid:
    print "You said yes"
else:
    print "You did not say yes"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether it's a member of a set:

```
if answer in {'Yes', 'yes', YES}:
    ...
```